# Show button reset when field value length more than 0?

Tags: javascript

I have a form search code like this :

```
<div class="search-box">
<form action="header.php" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<button class="search-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<input class="search-field" id="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
<button class="close-button" id="close-btn" type="reset" style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</form>
</div>
```

i want to show reset button when search-box length more than 0 by using javascript but my javascript can't work this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#search-box").length > 0){
      $('#close-btn').show();  
    }
    });
    $("#close-btn").click(function(e){
        $('#close-btn').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

What is wrong in my code ?

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check via `val().trim().length` (so that empty spaces alone do not count) - also, you should use a [**`keyup()`**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event to check the length if the input has been modified, otherwise you're only checking on page load (at which time it'll be empty):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
       $('#close-btn').toggle($(this).val().trim().length > 0); 
    });
    $("#close-btn").click(function(e){
        $('#close-btn').hide();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Qg7JN/2/)**

Comment: Thank's, you helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#search-box").val().length > 0){
      $('#close-btn').show();  
    }
    });
    $("#close-btn").click(function(e){
        $('#close-btn').hide();
    });
});
```

`.val()`, takes the value and `.length` checks for the length.

Answer (score 0):

You missed "." before `length`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($("#search-box").length > 0){
  $('#close-btn').show();  
}
});
$("#close-btn").click(function(e){
    $('#close-btn').hide();
});
```

});